# View mode tabs no longer visible

Tags: 8, entities

I added custom display settings on quite a few content types.

> [image: Custom display settings view]

The view mode tabs disappeared. I tried to uninstall third party modules and rebuild the cache, without luck.

> [image: Manage display view]

What can I try from here? I'm using Drupal 8.0.0-beta15.

Answer (score 2):

The block showing the secondary tab menu was disabled. In order to activate it, I had to pay `/admin/structure/block/list/seven` a visit and manually re-add the `Tabs` block to the `Pre-content` region.

[image: Seven admin theme tabs block]

Comment: Did you update from an earlier version? that sounds like a missing upgrade path, you might want to open a core bug if you can reproduce this (install beta14, then update, then all the blocks should be there).

Comment: @Berdir Yeah, it happened when I updated from beta14 -> beta15. I'll try to reproduce it if I got the time this weekend.